# Determine whether class is a record using Roslyn

Tags: c#, record, roslyn

I am writing a source generator and need to know whether a class that I am adding functionality to with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis is a record.

I can do this by switching to the syntax model, like this:

```
public static bool IsRecord(this ITypeSymbol type)
{
    if (type == null || type.TypeKind != TypeKind.Class)
        return false;
    bool isRecord = (type.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.Any(x => (x.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().FindNode(x.Span) is RecordDeclarationSyntax)));
    return isRecord;
}
```

But is there any way to do this with the semantic model? I may well be missing something obvious, but I've checked what seem to me to be the obvious places, and I've also searched on github. It seems that there is an [internal IsRecord](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/c9bd086b77a68ac6dd025022367c32cb12a8bcfb/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Symbols/Source/SourceMemberContainerSymbol.cs) within Roslyn, but I can't find anything publicly exposed. If I do not have access to this in the semantic model, will the above work even if the type is from code imported from another assembly?

Comment: So this is actually an open question for the Roslyn API that we're currently working on; if you don't mind me asking, why did you need to know if it was a record or not?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Source generation. When adding code to a class, I must include "partial record" or "partial class". For an example where this would be useful, see [this code](https://github.com/encrypt0r/FunWithSourceGenerators/blob/master/FunWithSourceGenerators/AsyncifyGenerator.cs) (not written by me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with 3.9.0-2.final version of the Roslyn API (this corresponds to Visual Studio 16.9 Preview 2), ITypeSymbol now has a IsRecord property you can use.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be any official public property IsRecord. So we are left to look for what a record would contain, such as an implicitly declared property named "EqualityContract":

```
type.GetMembers().Any(x => x.Kind == SymbolKind.Property && x.Name == "EqualityContract" && x.IsImplicitlyDeclared)
```